# Filter tree in Vaadin

Tags: java, tree, filtering, vaadin

I want to hide leafs from vaadin tree according to text in some editbox (on text change).
ie if text in editbox is "ab" i want to show only leafs with text starting with "ab".
and if text is empty, i want to show all leafs.

How can i make that?

Answer (score 3):

You will have to filter the data container which is attached to the tree.

A new Filter API was introduced in version 6.6.0 which allows you to create custom Filters. I haven't tried the new API yet, but in your case it should work like this:

```
textField.addListener(new FieldEvents.TextChangeListener() {
    void textChange(FieldEvents.TextChangeEvent event) {
        // Remove existing filter (if any).
        // This is OK if you don't use any other filters, otherwise you'll have to store the previous filter and use removeContainerFilter(filter)
        dataContainer.removeAllContainerFilters();

        // Create a new filter which ignores case and only matches String prefix
        SimpleStringFilter filter = new SimpleStringFilter(propertyId, event.getText(), true, true);

        // Add the new filter
        dataContainer.addContainerFilter(filter);
    }
});
```

in which *textField* is your "editbox", *dataContainer* is the data container which is attached to your tree and *properyId* is the property id of the container field which contains the text you want to filter.

Note that the above code is untested because I currently can't access the appropriate development tools.

Comment: tnx, but what if i have no dataContainer associated with the table? i mean what if i added the items explicit with the table.additem() method. how can i get the dataContainer here?

Comment: There's always a data container. If you don't provide one, Table will create it (IIRC IndexedContainer). You can access it via table.getContainerDataSource().

Comment: Tnx, but with that method i don't see no remove/add filters methods:( i guess that default container does not work with filters  EDIT - i think i got it working by doing this  IndexedContainer container = (IndexedContainer) valuesTable.getContainerDataSource();